# Android how to center align chips in chipgroup?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-chips

I tried `gravity="center"` , `foregroundGravity="center"` and `textAlignment="center"` for ChipGroup in the XML file but it won't work. Any ideas?

[image: This is how it looks now]

Comment: Hi M_droid, can I know how to fix this one, I am also using ChipGroup where the chips need to be aligned at center, please help me.

Comment: Where is your code? What you have tried, which library? Please put all the details.

Comment: Did you solve it ?

Comment: Sorry, haven‘t had a chance to test one of the answers yet. Back then we stopped using chips and after a few months the project was canceled anyway.

Comment: android:textAlignment="center" is working now

Comment: did you try using layout_width = wrap content?

Comment: @ladytoky0 no actually not.. Last thing I did was to use Flexbox like Ebrahim Byagowi suggested. Did `layout_width=wrap_content` work for you?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I tried using Chip inside [Flexbox](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) and it worked like this.

```
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:flexWrap="wrap"
        app:justifyContent="center"> ... </com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```

[image]

There should be better ways for achieving this but this will work there I guess.

Update (2021): I removed flexbox dependency due to stability and lack of updates from Google and am achieving the same effect using ConstraintLayout's Flow nowadays, anyone using the technique perhaps can consider that also, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/61545990 to fill it programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for the solution!

Comment: I finally got around to check your answer and it works. But a solution without using flexbox would be better though. Anyway, for now I will accept yours.

Answer (score 6):

Put it into a LinearLayout and make its gravity  "center_horizontal". Then set the chip group's layout_width to "wrap_content". This worked for me.

```
    <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">


                <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/langsChipGroup"
                    >

                </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 6):

If you have your `ChipGroup` in a `ConstraintLayout`, use

```
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```

as such:

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
        android:id="@+id/chips"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
...
```

Be sure not to set the `layout_width` field to be `match_parent`, as it wouldn't work that way.

Answer (score 1):

This library is help you for figure out your query. please check it.and let me know your thoughts for the same.

The ChipCloud library was originally a (very) quickly knocked up Android view for some larger hackathon project by fiskurgit. It creates a wrapping cloud of material ' Chips'. Basic demo of their version is available on the Play Store - I'm maintaining this fork for features I required in it.

[Chip Cloud View](https://github.com/adroitandroid/ChipCloud?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=5246)

Comment: Just copy paste their library description. You should put example with link.

Comment: Yes @PratikButani you can check example in the library.

Comment: What if they will remove examples or removed this link? Thats why always put code with example so every one can understand.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing thinking that it will help someone. I had a similar problem. But I had a ***single line***. And I solved this problem in the following form

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding"
            app:singleLine="true">

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Entry"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Entry"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

//          ...

         </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
     </HorizontalScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'm glad if I helped someone.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the width of "com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup" to wrap_content ; "match_parent" won't work.
2. Set the width of each individual chip to "match_parent"
3. Bonus - to add space between chips add the "app:chipSpacingHorizontal="20dp"" or "app:chipSpacingVertical="20dp"" attribute to the ChipGroup widget.

Answer (score -6):

Put the width of chip group into `wrap_content` and make the parent view to gravity to `center` which contains chip group. So that it will be aligned center.

Answer (score -15):

Please try following :

```
layout_gravity="center"
```

Hope this will help you.