# android:unable to make multiline chipgroup

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, androidx, android-chips

I have a chipgroup within a relative layout along with a textview whose code is shown below.

```
    <RelativeLayout
    ...

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextTitle"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/cg"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/cg"
        />

       <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
       android:id="@+id/cg"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="14dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
       android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
       android:textColor="@android:color/black"
       android:textStyle="bold"
       android:textSize="12sp"
       app:singleSelection="false"
       app:chipSpacingVertical="32dp"
       app:chipSpacingHorizontal="5dp"
       app:singleLine="false"
       />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

I add chips to this chipgroup dynamically like the below:

```
Chip chip;

for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    chip = new Chip(this);
    chip.setText("Text:"+i);
    chip.setChipBackgroundColorResource(android.R.color.darker_gray);
    chip.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    mChipGroup.addView(chip);
}
```

The above brings the textview and chipgroup side by side (with the chips at the extreme right from the textview,which is what I want).

**For 2 or 3 chips the output looks like this:**

[image]

**But when I have more than 3 chips,it looks bad like this:**

[image]

I referred the docs and tried to make the chipgroup multiline and added the following in chipgroup xml

```
   app:chipSpacingVertical="32dp"
   app:chipSpacingHorizontal="5dp"
   app:singleLine="false"
```

It looks the same as in the pic2.

**What I need is a chipgroup with multiline option with spacing as that in the pic1,i.e in the pic1 , I want Text3 beneath Text0 and Text4 beneath Text1 and so on, if the no of chips increases!**.

Im sure I must be missing something,but dont know what it is.Any help will be very useful.Thanks in advance!!

Comment: check my answer

Comment: do you want all your chips to be displayed in single line?

Comment: No I want them to be in multiple lines with their respective sizes as shown in the pics above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I update from @Sajith 's answer,see if it could work:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextTitle"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:id="@+id/tv" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="75"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
                android:id="@+id/cg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:singleSelection="false"
                app:chipSpacingVertical="32dp"
                app:chipSpacingHorizontal="5dp"
                app:singleLine="false" />
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Its awesome dude..it is the one which I need.btw, what is the trick? is it using framelayout? if so when shall we employ framelayout ?

Comment: I'm happy it works.The timing of using FrameLayout is difficult to generalize, but you can master it with more use of it.

Comment: if we replace framelayout, with linear or any other layout, it works then also?

Comment: I had the same kind of issue. I already encountered issues in which FrameLayout was the trick, but I did not no in this case. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

use your xml like below

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextTitle"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
        android:id="@+id/cg"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="75"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:singleSelection="false"
        app:chipSpacingVertical="32dp"
        app:chipSpacingHorizontal="5dp"
        app:singleLine="false"
        />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and your final screen  would be like below . Adjust space and width of chips according to your requirement.

[image: output screen]

**EDIT**

if you want to set height use it like below in your activity (inside `for` loop)

```
 chip.setChipMinHeight(10);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sajith.But I want the chip size to be small .I gave 4 chips, and its looking very big with extra gaps .I had set layout_height, but two chips went out of frame.I want the chip size to be exactly as shown in my pic with the multiline which you had brought.Could you suggest something on this pls!!

Comment: Can you upvote and accept my answer if it is the answer you are lookin for?

Comment: Hi Sajith,even though, it makes the chip multiline, it doesn't align the chips to right like shown in pic1.Say I have 2 chips,they should be aligned to the right, but now it is aligned to the left, could you give some input in it!!

Comment: you have answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51199787/android-how-to-center-align-chips-in-chipgroup

Answer (score 1):

All of the previous solutions didn't work for me if you want to achieve a gmail like behaviour with chips on multiple lines. In order to do that I had to avoid using the ChipGroup and instead using a **FlexboxLayout**.

[image]

**your_recipient_layout:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recipient_label_TV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
        android:id="@+id/recipient_group_FL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        app:flexWrap="wrap"
        app:alignItems="stretch"
        app:alignContent="space_around"
        app:showDivider="beginning|middle|end"
        app:dividerDrawable="@drawable/divider">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/recipient_input_ET"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            app:layout_flexGrow="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="text"/>

    </com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recipients_list_RV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

The trick now is adding a new chip to the group but as second last position. Something like this:

```
private fun addChipToGroup(person: String, chipGroup: FlexboxLayout) {
    val chip = Chip(context)
    chip.text = person
    chip.chipIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
    chip.isCloseIconEnabled = true
    chip.isClickable = true
    chip.isCheckable = false
    chipGroup.addView(chip as View, chipGroup.childCount - 1)
    chip.setOnCloseIconClickListener { chipGroup.removeView(chip as View) }
}
```