# android chips taking extra spaces;unable to wrap

Tags: android, android-layout, material-components-android, material-components, android-chips

I use chipgroup with dynamic chips. I want the chips to get wrapped in width according to their text. But it takes extra spaces even without padding.

Below is my code:

xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
    android:id="@+id/cg"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="75"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:singleSelection="false"
    app:chipSpacingVertical="5dp"
    app:chipSpacingHorizontal="5dp"
    app:singleLine="false"
    app:chipSpacing="2dp">
```

This is how to add chips dynamically:

```
for(int i=0;i<cartoonTypes.length;i++){
    chip = new Chip(this);
    chip.setText(cartoonTypes[i].trim());
    chip.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    chip.setChipBackgroundColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorChip));
    chip.setTextSize(12);
    chip.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    chip.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
    cgMovieGenre.addView(chip);
    ChipGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = (ChipGroup.LayoutParams) chip.getLayoutParams();;
    int dpSize = px2dp(12);;
    layoutParams.height = dpSize;
    layoutParams.width = ChipGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    chip.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

method px2dp does this:

```
int px2dp(int px){
    metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    int h = (px * metrics.densityDpi) / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT;
    return h;
}
```

My `build.gradle` has the following dependencies:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
```

This is what I see:

[image: screenshot, chip-group]

I want the chip to use as minimal width as possible according to its text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should set padding for chip in right way, try this:

```
chip.setChipStartPadding(0);
chip.setChipEndPadding(0);
```

Comment: It reduces the space, but still has some space left and my gravity attribute is not working.It has some space on top even after trying many gravity attributes!

Comment: I increased my chip height, and the gravity is fine now, but there is some more space present on the  left and right..any inputs on them !!

Comment: Add setTextStartPadding(0) and setTextEndPadding(0) to see if it would better meet your needs.

Comment: thanks, but there is an extra space only on the right now for some texts inspite of trimming the strings!

Comment: if u dont mind could u have a look at this post on Sajith's answer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56244817/androidunable-to-make-multiline-chipgroup/56245456?noredirect=1#comment99143166_56245456

Comment: It is not totally correct. The issue is not this padding. Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58246871/2016562): you can check how the padding works inside a chip.

Answer (score 5):

Just **remove** in your code this line

```
//chip.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
```

The result with and without the padding:

[image]
[image]

Just to understand the padding inside the `Chip`:

```
 * <pre>
 *   chipStartPadding     iconEndPadding     closeIconStartPadding         chipEndPadding
 *    +                    +                                    +                      +
 *    |                    |                                    |                      |
 *    |  iconStartPadding  |  textStartPadding   textEndPadding | closeIconEndPadding  |
 *    |   +                |    +                            +  |                  +   |
 *    |   |                |    |                            |  |                  |   |
 *    v   v                v    v                            v  v                  v   v
 * +-----+----+-----------+----+----+---------------------+----+----+----------+----+-----+
 * |     |    |       XX  |    |    |  XX   X  X  X  XXX  |    |    | X      X |    |     |
 * |     |    |      XX   |    |    | X  X  X  X  X  X  X |    |    |  XX  XX  |    |     |
 * |     |    |  XX XX    |    |    | X     XXXX  X  XXX  |    |    |    XX    |    |     |
 * |     |    |   XXX     |    |    | X  X  X  X  X  X    |    |    |  XX  XX  |    |     |
 * |     |    |    X      |    |    |  XX   X  X  X  X    |    |    | X      X |    |     |
 * +-----+----+-----------+----+----+---------------------+----+----+----------+----+-----+
 *                  ^                           ^                         ^
 *                  |                           |                         |
 *                  +                           +                         +
 *             chipIconSize                  *dynamic*              closeIconSize
 * </pre>
```

Also some notes:

- The `chip.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);` **doesn't** work because *chip text must be vertically center and start aligned*.
  Chip **uses** a built-in `setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.START);`
- Instead of `chip.setChipBackgroundColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorChip));` use the method `chip.setChipBackgroundColorResource(R.color.colorChip)`

Comment: how to remove vertical padding?

Comment: This is awesome! In my case I wasn't setting the textStartPadding

Answer (score 3):

For chips, it's not (inner) "padding", but (outer) "spacing":

- `app:chipSpacing`  —  Adds spacing to both the horizontal and vertical axis.
- `app:chipSpacingHorizontal`  —  Adds spacing to the horizontal axis.
- `app:chipSpacingVertical`  —  Adds spacing to the vertical axis.

the least spacing with line-wrapping would be:

```
app:singleLine="false"
app:chipSpacing="0dp"
```

alternatively, wrap the `ChipGroup` in a `HorizontalScrollView` with `app:singleLine="true"`.

Answer (score 3):

Probably just removing *chip.setTextSize()* may help you get rid of the space on the right (however, I'm still wondering how to change the font size).
If not, this is the solution I use in my project:

1. Define a style for your chips:

```
    <style name="ListChip" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Entry" >
        <style name="ListChip" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Entry" >
        <item name="rippleColor">@null</item>
        <item name="closeIcon">@null</item>
        <item name="chipBackgroundColor">?attr/background_highlight_color</item>
        <item name="android:checkable">false</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">8sp</item> //This has not effect
        <item name="android:textColor">?attr/text_color</item>
    </style>
```

2. Create a layout resource file with the root element  *com.google.android.material.chip.Chip* and apply the newly created style:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        style="@style/ListChip"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:ellipsize="end">
     </com.google.android.material.chip.Chip>
```

3. In the code, create your chips not by using *Chip chip = new Chip(this);* but by inflating the newly created chip layout:

```
    Chip chip = (Chip) LayoutInflater.from(chipGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chip_in_list, chipGroup, false);
```

4. Do not call *chip.setTextSize()* on the newly created chip.

Answer (score 1):

I was creating chips programmatically so i had to do this in kotlin:

```
chip.minimumWidth = 0
chip.setEnsureMinTouchTargetSize(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

that extra space is of close icon ,
just set this

```
val chip = Chip(this)
chip.closeIcon = null
```

Answer (score 0):

In the new `<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip` there is an attribute called app:chipMinTouchTargetSize.This will get rid of the extra spaces

```
app:chipMinHeight="20dp"
app:chipMinTouchTargetSize="22dp"
```

Answer (score -1):

first thing first, create you attr (values/attrs.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="ChipView">
        <attr name="CustomChipStyle" format="reference"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

after that add to your theme
set your R.attr.CustomChipChoiceStyle to your theme (values/styles.xml) example:

```
<style name="APPTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/secondaryColor</item>
    <item name="CustomChipChoiceStyle">@style/ChipTextAppearance</item>
</style>

    <style name="ChipTextAppearance" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice">
        <item name="android:minWidth">130dp</item>
        <item name="chipMinHeight">50dp</item>
<item name="android:textAlignment">center</item>
    </style>
```

if you have a chipGroup like this:

```
    <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
        android:id="@+id/chipGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:singleSelection="true"/>
```

you can add from code something like that:

```
val list = listOf("credit", "cash")
list.forEach{
            val chip = Chip(context, null, R.attr.CustomChipStyle).apply {
                text = it
            }
            chipGroup.addView(chip)
        }
```

and that's it.

[image]